# Is it possible to see protected Twitter accounts?

Tags: twitter

Is it possible to see protected Twitter accounts (accounts which you can't see what they are tweeting until they allow you to follow) without them knowing?

Comment: What do you mean by "secret" accounts?

Comment: That would kind of defeat the purpose of a "secret" account, no?

Comment: A bit strange question! Isn't it something, that we should consider to report to Twitter? :}

Answer (score 4):

No, unless the owner of the account has accepted your follow request, there's no way to see the tweets of a protected account has approved your follow request.

From [Twitter's support document](http://support.twitter.com/articles/14016-about-public-and-protected-tweets):

> When you protect your Tweets, the following restrictions are put in
>   place:
>
> - People will have to request to follow you; each follow request will need approval. Learn more.
> - Your Tweets will only be visible to users you've approved.
> - Other users will not be able to retweet your Tweets. Learn more.
> - Protected Tweets will not appear in Twitter search or Google search.
> - @Replies you send to people who aren't following you will not be seen by those users  (because you have not given them permission to
>     see your Tweets).
> - You cannot share permanent links to your Tweets with anyone other than your approved followers.

Unless of course, the Twitter account holder removes the protected account status for a short while—in which case the tweets will be visible until the account status is changed to protected.